# losing decimal precision when updating MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, save, decimal

I have two columns in my database BuyCommission and SellCommission, both are defined as DECIMAL.  However, when my program executes the following:

```
UPDATE lots 
SET BidValue = '13', Buyer ='2',LotSold = 'S', SellCommission = '1.30', 
    BuyCommission = '1.30'  
WHERE AuctionID = '1' AND LotNumber = '28'
```

the value shown in the columns is 1, no decimal portion is being saved.  Am I using the correct type in defining the column to be DECIMAL?

Comment: What is the decimal precision of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the `DECIMAL` datatype, you can specify how many total digits (the *precision*) and how many digits after the decimal point (the *scale*), in the form:

```
DECIMAL(precision, scale)
```

If you don't specify the scale, it defaults to `0`, so it's just an integer. If you want to be able to store 10 digit numbers with 2 decimal places, declare the column to be

```
DECIMAL(10,2)
```

See the MySQL documentation of [Fixed Point Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your fields are decimal you don't need to use single quotes in set: `...., SellCommission = 1.3,...`.  With single quote you have a string value ('1.3') that implicitly converted to decimal (depends on locale settings , say decimal separator is comma , it may be converted to 1).